Compiling old packages with outdated libraries for modern distros for preservation and archival purposes
I want to compile old (2005-2012) commits of an app, the app in question uses outdated libraries that no longer exist in modern distros, for example Qt3/Qt4 and ancient OpenSSL. I was successfully able to compile the app under Ubuntu 6.06 and 8.04, but due to missing libraries it would obviously not run on modern distros. My first thought was to compile the binaries statically, but I failed since I would need to statically rebuild the libraries too. I want to compile the app for preservation and archival purposes, and I want it to run out of the box on modern distros, shipping it in something like AppImage maybe? Is statically compiling the dependencies the best way? Or is there a better way?

Complete VM images might really be an option, as often apps that specifically died with their old environments are special because of that environment, so preserving the whole environment might make sense from an archival point of view.


AppImage/Snap/FlatPak should all work beautifully granted if you're able to use them in that old distro.

Personally I'd still compile this app statically. There are distros that provide static libraries, e.g. I'm looking at Fedora and there's a lot!

You can compile normally, use something like ldd or strace to find out what the apps needs, copy all the dependencies into a new root, and run the app via chroot.



Which Fedora version would I have to use to get Qt3 libraries? Something like Fedora 10 would have them probably?

Even Fedora 40 contains Qt3 but not its statically linked version.
